# jQuery Mobile and Bootstrap in the same application

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

I am working on a web application that is to be used by desktop browsers as well as mobile device browsers. I am considering using Bootstrap for all CSS/styling for all types of users (Desktop and Mobile) and jQuery Mobile for mobile oriented features. This application needs to work very well on both Desktop and on Mobile devices since the user base for both will be large.

I do not want to build two separate sites, one for desktop and one for mobile but instead only one to share as much code as possible.

Is this a good approach or do you have any better ideas?
Will I encounter any conflicts between Bootstrap and jQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding:

> jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js
>   jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.css

For functionality like ajax navigation and structure (animations).

But not add the jquery-mobile **theme stylesheet**.

Also you could use bootstrap for styling your markup